# Build ZBar for 64bit WIndows

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, zbar

The [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) library is distributed with a 32bit binary lib file and dll. I need to use ZBar in a 64bit Windows application. It seems that the only way to get 64bit version of ZBar is to build it yourself.

According to this [faq](https://zbarcodereader.wordpress.com/faq/), the only way to build ZBar is by using MinGW. I also found this [patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/patches/28/) for patching ZBar in order to produce a 64bit build.

Of course I can try to follow these suggestions and try to build ZBar, but since I have never built ZBar before, and I don't know MinGW at all (I am a VC++ user), I was wandering if anyone has built a 64bit version of ZBar for Windows successfully. Maybe there is even someone that can share the binaries with the rest of us. Any suggestion is welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there were no answers I assume that there is no available 64 build. I therefore decided to do it myself. Since I don't know MinGW and [the link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/zbar/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Compile_with_MinGW_in_Windows)  from the zbar faq seems to be broken, I decided to build using VS2013.

The code for the VS2013 project and the adapted ZBar code can be found in https://github.com/dani4/ZBarWin64. I also added the built libraries themselves. See the README for details.

I am new to github so possibly my choice to change a fork of ZBar wasn't the right one, and I should have created a new repository. Anyway I think that the library can be used in this form as well.

Comment: Good for you, but ZBar is still abandonware. I do not mean to start a platform war, but ZXLib is a Google sponsored project.

Comment: I cannot find ZXLib.  Do you have a link?